# What is the correct way of presenting a List of UserControls using WPF MVVM without using code-behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, observablecollection

I'm trying to create a WPF MVVM program in which a client will download a list of files from the server, show them to the user and allow them to download those files.

I have already developed the server but I'm struggling with presentation of that list.

I already have:Created BaseViewModel, Created RelayCommand, Created MainViewModel, Created DownloadViewModel, which contains ObservableCollection of RemoteDiscElementViewModels, which is a ViewModel of a single file from the server, Created RemoteDiscElementView, Created DownloadView

ObservableCollection loads properly, but as I bind the collection to ItemsControl proper amount of RemoteDiscElementViews renders, but they are all empty.

DownloadViewModel:

```
public class DownloadViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<RemoteDiscElementViewModel> RemoteDiscElementViewModels { get; set; }
    public static DownloadViewModel Download1;
    void Awake()
    {
        Download1 = this;
    }
    public DownloadViewModel()
    {
        Client = new Client();
        RemoteDiscElementViewModels = new ObservableCollection<RemoteDiscElementViewModel>();
    }
    public DownloadViewModel(string address, int port)
    {
        Client = new Client(address, port);
        RemoteDiscElementViewModels = new ObservableCollection<RemoteDiscElementViewModel>();
        Client.Connect();
        GetFiles();
    }

    public void GetFiles()
    {
        RemoteDiscElementViewModels.Clear();
        var content = Client.ListFiles();
        foreach(var file in content)
        {
            RemoteDiscElementViewModel newFile = new RemoteDiscElementViewModel(file.Type, file.Filename, file.Filepath, file.Fileext, file.Filesize);
            RemoteDiscElementViewModels.Add(newFile);
        }
    }



}
```

RemoteDiscElementViewModel:

```
public class RemoteDiscElementViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string type;
    private string filename;
    private string filepath;
    private int filesize;
    private string fileext;
    private bool isDownloaded;

    public RemoteDiscElementViewModel()
    {

    }
    public RemoteDiscElementViewModel(string type, string filename, string filepath, string fileext, int filesize)
    {
        Type = type;
        Filename = filename;
        Filepath = filepath;
        Fileext = fileext;
        Filesize = filesize;
        IsDownloaded = false;

    }

    public void Download()
    {
        DownloadViewModel.Download1.Client.SendFile(Filename);
    }
}
```

RemoteDiscElementView:

```
 <UserControl x:Class="sikFtpClient.View.RemoteDiscElementView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:sikFtpClient.View"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:sikFtpClient.ViewModel"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:RemoteDiscElementViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Content="{Binding Filename}" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding DownloadCommand}" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

What is a proper way of displaying a ObservableCollection of UserControls without using Code Behind?

Comment: I don't see xaml part with `ItemsControl`. Did you use data templates or redefine `ItemTemplate`?

Comment: Bind itemssource to the observablecollection. Either define an itemtemplate which is your row usercontrol or associate the usercontrol with a row viewmodel type using datatype. Remove that datacontext from your usercontrol.

Comment: `public static DownloadViewModel Download1;` <= this is not correct ... `RemoteDiscElementViewModel` eventually should have property called `Parent` with type of  `DownloadViewModel` ... you may set it via constructor

Answer (score 0):

DownloadView can be written like this, for example:

```
<UserControl...>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(local:DownloadViewModel.RemoteDiscElementViewModels), Mode=OneWay}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:RemoteDiscElementViewModel}">
                <local:RemoteDiscElementView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</UserControl>
```

In "RemoteDiscElementView", you also don't need the following code:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:RemoteDiscElementViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Because the DataContext is implicitely set by the ListBox on its childrens.

Finally, make sure that "DownloadView" has its DataContext set to a DownloadViewModel object.

Edit:

Added the following properties in "RemoteDiscElementViewModel":

```
public String Type => _type;
public String Filename => _filename;
public String Filepath => _filepath;
public Int32 Filesize => _filesize;
public String Fileext => _fileext;
public Boolean IsDownloaded => _isDownloaded;
```

Used dummy data for Client.ListFiles() function:

```
public List<RemoteDiscElementViewModel> ListFiles() {
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 20).Select(i => new RemoteDiscElementViewModel("type", "file", "filepath", "fileext", 5)).ToList();
}
```

And used the constructor of "DownloadViewModel" using the address and port and it displayed something:

[image: Test]

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but unluckily it's not working. The list ends up being rendered empty.

Comment: In "RemoteDiscElementView" you try to display properties "Filename" and "DownloadCommand" but they don't exist in class "RemoteDiscElementViewModel"

Comment: @KubaGutry Edited the answer and tested the solution. It works. Look at the "output" window for binding errors in Visual Studio, if you use this IDE.

Comment: As a note, it doesn't make sense to set DataType on a DataTemplate that is assigned to the ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl. Setting DataType is only necessary when a DataTemplate is used as resource and supposed to be selected automatically for a data item of the specified type.

Comment: Thanks captain, I owe you a beer! @nkoniishvt

Comment: @Clemens It's convenient for completion in IDE, but indeed in this case it's useless because we don't use any binding to properties from RemoteDiscElementViewModel. Same thing for the path of the binding, where the type is explicit.

Comment: RemoteDiscElement's Properties were there for the whole time I just couldn't paste any more code snippets due to the lentght restrictions so I decided to cut them out since they seemed to be the most obvious part of code.